# How to Deploy Fabric Network on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I want to deploy the hyperledger fabric network on Kubernetes, can anyone guide me or provide the sample docs for the same

Comment: What a wide question... As any other network over Kubernetes, taking much care about persistent volumes, network-related configuration, etc. You require knowledge about Hyperledger Fabric and Kubernetes. It is not trivial. Don't expect anyone to do all that work for you. You have some examples such as https://github.com/feitnomore/hyperledger-fabric-kubernetes, but I'll prefer etcd-raft over Kafka/Zookeper and you probably want to customize a lot of things for your Fabric network and Kubernetes infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks @kekomal I will refer link provided by you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find amazing documentation along with examples in [Hyperledger Fabric meets Kubernetes](https://github.com/APGGroeiFabriek/PIVT). I have tested with 1.4.1 HL Fabric binaries  - works fine.

---

### Requirements

- A running Kubernetes cluster, Minikube should also work, but not
  tested
- [HL Fabric
  binaries](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html)
  (There is an
  [issue](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-16376?focusedCommentId=63968&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-63968)
  with cryptogen 1.4.3, so use 1.4.2 or 1.4.1)
- [Helm](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.11.0), developed
  with 2.11, newer 2.xx versions should also work
- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) 1.5+ and
- [yq](https://pypi.org/project/yq/) 2.6+
- [Argo](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/demo.md), both
  CLI and Controller 2.4.0+
- [Minio](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/ARTIFACT_REPO.md),
  only required for backup/restore and new-peer-org flows
- Run all the commands in fabric-kube folder
- AWS EKS users please also apply this
  [fix](https://github.com/APGGroeiFabriek/PIVT/issues/1)

---

1) Run cluster and install helm

2) clone repo `git clone https://github.com/APGGroeiFabriek/PIVT.git`

3) Install  HL Fabric binaries

```
$curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 1.4.1 1.4.1 0.4.18

$export PATH=$PATH:/path-to-fabric-kube-dir/fabric-samples/bin (path to `cryptogen` bin)

$./init.sh ./samples/simple/ ./samples/chaincode/

-- creating certificates --
aptalkarga.tr
nevergreen.nl
atlantis.com
-- creating genesis block --
...
creating hlf-kube/chaincode/very-simple.tar
creating hlf-kube/chaincode/even-simpler.tar
```

4) install chart dependencies

```
$helm repo add kafka http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator    
$helm dependency update ./hlf-kube/
```

5) **inside fabric-kube folder** launch the network:

```
helm install ./hlf-kube --name hlf-kube -f samples/simple/network.yaml -f samples/simple/crypto-config.yaml
...
Happy BlockChaining :)

And don't forget the first rule of BlockChain club:

"Do not use BlockChain unless absolutely necessary!"
```